# If Mermaids Were Sea Lions Instead of Fish

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, mammals

The most popular image of the mermaid is a half-girl, half-fish beauty.  Biologically, physiologically and evolutionarily, this sort of mixing is 0% compatible.

I'm also not going for the half-girl, half-whale alternative because I have a feeling that it's been done several times before.

No, this kind of mermaid is half-girl, half-sea-lion.  Let's assume that such a human-sea-lion half-and-half exists.  Physically, biologically and behaviorally, where would the human end make way for the sea lion end?

Comment: Have you considered dolphins?

Comment: For the sake of this argument, whales and dolphins are generally the same.

Comment: In myths mermaids transitioned anywhere from just below the human breasts to just above the human pelvis.  Modern images tend towards the later to add a bit of erotic flavor to the pictures.  Since this isn't really science based, you could probably put the transition anywhere you wanted between breasts and pelvic girdle.

Comment: Chances are that having sea lion legs instead of a fish/cetacean tail would make them a little better at moving on land, much like how you see with seals vs sea lions.

Answer (score 2):

[Selkies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selkie) are Irish/Scottish creatures from folklore which can exist in seal of human forms. As they transform by removing the seal skin layer to reveal the humanoid underneath, there are some beautiful pictures of the transitional state.  If you remove context, they appear to be what you want.

I'm sorry but the image upload is not working well for me:

[image: Girl holding a seal skin sitting among seals]

[image: Faerie girl removing a seal skin]

Comment: They seem fine to me.  How did you mean by "removing context"?

Comment: They are are never both human-like and seal-like...  they look like seals when in water but take off their seal skin when they come to shore.  These pictures are of them taking off their seal skin.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the pictures; I think my server was blocking imgur when i tried to upload them.

Comment: And if you've ever seen the movie "Local Hero", there were several clues that one of the characters (Marina) was a selkie... in the traditional mythology, if you hid the character's sealskin, they were trapped in human form (you could marry, etc) but if they found the hidden sealskin, even years later, they would take off.